# What does ^:internal mean in clojure?

Tags: clojure

What does `^:internal` mean in clojure? e.g. the macro `defnilsafe` defined in arrows.clj(https://github.com/rplevy/swiss-arrows/blob/1.0.0/src/swiss/arrows.clj) has `^:internal` between `defmacro` and the macro name `defnilsafe`.

Comment: as far as i know, the `^:internal` metadata is merely a marker for library users, and the repository readers and comitters. it is purely conventional, and could easily be `^:notice-this-is-for-internal-use-only` or anything else. For example, this macro could mutate some internal state, while not being idempotent.. So the author warns you by adding this metadata. It doesnt' mean it is private, (that's why it is not `^:private`) still, you should use it only if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that before.

As @leetwinksi said, it appears to be an "internal" note-keeping thing by the authors. Pretty non-standard and I have no idea about the intended usage.

Please remember: metadata is "stuff that doesn't affect equality".  It is a kind of "escape hatch" where you can append information that won't affect an equality comparison.  It is of very limited use.